# Nonlinear plot for linear complex polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have a linear complex polynomial. When I plot the polynomial,the real part generates a linear plot but the imaginary part generates me a highly nonlinear plot with bifurcations. My question is

1. Is it possible that a linear polynomial gives a real and a nonlinear plot?
2. How can I remove the nonlinearity so as to generate an approximate linear plot for the complex polynomial?

Comment: What specifically is the polynomial?

Comment: And how are you plotting it?

Answer (score 0):

The imaginary part of the linear equation which gives nonlinear plot is as given below:

> Blockquote

> y = (-q11*(1/xi - I k) -
> x*(q22*(1/xi + I k) - q33*(1/xi + I k)*(I k - 1/xi) -
> q44*(1/xi^2 + k^2) - q55*(1/xi - I k)))/(p22 +
> p33*(I k - 1/xi) - p55*(1/xi^2 + k^2))

I'm plotting it using mathematica 9.0
The code is as given below:

> Blockquote

> ```
> omegaJ = 4*10^-15;                     
> lambdaJ = 10^12;                                
> zion = 1.602*10^-19;                           (*ion
> ```

```
  charge*)
```

> ```
> e = 1.602*10^-19;                                     >     (*electron \
> ```

```
  charge*)
```

> ```
> teqlb = 10^6;                                   (*
> ```

```
  equilibrium temp *)
```

> ```
> melec = 9.1094*10^-31;         (* mass of electron *)
> ionFreq = 
> 1.00*10^1;             (* rate of electron impact 
> ionization of \
> neutral atoms*)
> freqID = 5.00*10^-3;            (* ion-dust 
> attachment frequency*)
> freqED = 1.00*10^2;              (* electron-dust 
> attachment \
> frequency*)
> rdust = 37.5*10^-6;              (* dust radius *)
> mion = 2*10^-14;                        (*ion mass *)
> mnd = 4.0*10^-16;                     (*-ve dust 
> mass*)
> ```

> ```
> grav = 6.67*10^-11;           (*gravitational 
> constant*)
> visco = 12*10^-6;                             
> (*viscosity*)
> cs = 4*10^-3;                        (*sound speed *)
> ne0 = 5*10^3;                                           
> (*eqlb \
> electron density*)
> ni0 = 10^3;                                                  
> (*eqlb \
> ion density*)
> nnd0 = 1.39*10^1;                                   
> (*eqlb negative \
> dust density*)
> veff = ionFreq/(2*
> ni0)  ;               (* difference between volume 
> recomination \
> rate and stepwise ionization rate *)
> ```

> ```
> znd0 = 10^4;                                          
> (*negative dust \
> charge*)
> qnd0 = -znd0*e;                            
> (*equilibrium dust charge*)
> ```

> ```
> etemp = 10^5;
> itemp = 10^4;
> ```

> ```
> Subscript[i, e0] = 
> Abs[-\[Pi] *rdust^2*e*((8*etemp)/(\> 
> [Pi]*melec))^0.5*ne0*
> Exp[(e*qnd0)/(rdust*etemp)]];          (*electron 
> current*)
> Subscript[i, i0] = 
> Abs[\[Pi]*rdust^2*e*((8*itemp)/(\[Pi]*mion))^0.5*
> ni0*(1 - (e*qnd0)/(rdust*itemp))]  ;            (*Ion >     current *)
> ndCf = 10^4*
> e;                                        (*-ve dust  
> charging \
>  frequency*)
> ```

> ```
> c = (-freqED + ionFreq - 2*ne0*veff)/omegaJ;
> d = (3*visco*omegaJ)/(melec*ne0*lambdaJ*xi^2) + 
>     (visco*omegaJ*k^2)/(
>     melec*ne0*lambdaJ);
> h = ((3*visco)/(lambdaJ*nnd0*mnd*xi^2))*omegaJ;
> ```

> ```
> gamma = (4*\[Pi]*e^2*lambdaJ^2)/teqlb ;  
> beta = (qnd0*nnd0)/e;
> ```

> ```
> a1 = teqlb/(mion*cs^2);
> a2 = -zion*ni0*omegaJ*a1;
> a3 = -zion*ni0*(2*veff*ni0 - ionFreq);
> a4 = -(beta*Subscript[i, e0])/qnd0;
> a5 = (beta*Subscript[i, i0]*(2*veff*ni0 - 
>       ionFreq))/qnd0;
> a6 = (beta*Subscript[i, i0]*omegaJ*a1)/qnd0;
> r5 = (qnd0*teqlb*omegaJ)/(e*mnd*cs);
> r6 = (qnd0*teqlb)/(e*lambdaJ*mnd);
> r8 = -(1/(melec*lambdaJ) + 
>       (teqlb*qnd0*omegaJ)/(e*mnd));
> r9 = (2*teqlb*k)/(melec*lambdaJ);
> r10 = (2*teqlb*k)/(lambdaJ*mnd);
> ```

> ```
> d1 = h*d*c*freqID*ndCf;
> d6 = r10*c*d*freqID*ndCf;
> d11 = h*d*c*ndCf;
> d15 = c*d*r10*ndCf;
> d16 = d*c*freqID;
> ```

> ```
> e4 = d*r10*freqID*ndCf - c*d*r10*ndCf*omegaJ - 
>      c*d*r10*freqID*omegaJ -
>      c*r10*cs*omegaJ*freqID*ndCf;
> e11 = d*r10*ndCf - c*d*r10*omegaJ - 
>       c*r10*ndCf*cs*omegaJ;
> e13 = d*freqID - d*c*omegaJ - c*freqID - cs*omegaJ;
>       p11 = a2*d15 + a6*r10*c*d;           
>       p22 = a2*d11 + a6*h*d*c ;           
>       p33 = r8*h*a3*ndCf - r8*h*ne0*freqID*ndCf + 
>       r8*h*a4*freqID + 
>       r8*h*a5 + beta (r5 + r6)*d16*omegaJ;
> p44 = r8*r10*a3*ndCf - r8*r10*ne0*freqID*ndCf + 
>       r8*r10*a4*freqID + 
>       r8*r10*a5;
> p55 = d1/gamma;
> p66 = d6/gamma;
> ```

> ```
> q11 = -beta*(r5 + r6)*d16*ndCf;    
> q22 =  a2*e11 + a6*r10*d - a6*c*cs*omegaJ*r10;  
> q33 = r8*r10*a3*omegaJ + r8*r10*ne0*freqID*omegaJ + 
>       r8*r10*ne0*ndCf*omegaJ - r8*r10*a4*omegaJ;                        
> q44 = e4/gamma;
> q55 = e13*ndCf;
> ```

> ```
> y = Range[1, 10];
> x = Range[1, 10];
> visco = 13*10^-6;
> y = (-q11*(1/xi - I k) - 
> x*(q22*(1/xi + I k) - q33*(1/xi + I k)*(I k - 1/xi) - 
>    q44*(1/xi^2 + k^2) - q55*(1/xi - I k)))/(p22 + 
>    p33*(I k - 1/xi) - p55*(1/xi^2 + k^2));
> y = y*10^-14;
> Plot[{Im[y] /. {xi -> 100}, Im[y] /. xi -> 500, 
> Im[y] /. xi -> 1000}, {k, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
> PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Blue, >     Dashed, Thick], 
> Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed]}, Frame -> True, 
> FrameStyle -> Thick, 
> PlotLegends -> {"K for \[Xi] = 100", "K for \[Xi] = 
>  500", 
> "K for \[Xi] = 1000"}, 
> FrameLabel -> {"Wave number (K)", 
> "Imaginary frequency (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\ 
>   [CapitalOmega]\), \
> \(i\)]\))"}, RotateLabel -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
> ```

> ```
> Plot[{Im[y] /. {xi -> 10}, Im[y] /. xi -> 50, Im[y] 
> /. xi -> 100}, {k,
> 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
> PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Blue, >     Dashed, Thick], 
> Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed]}, Frame -> True, 
> FrameStyle -> Thick, 
> PlotLegends -> {"K for \[Xi] = 10", "K for \[Xi] = 
>  50", 
> "K for \[Xi] = 100"}, 
> FrameLabel -> {"Wave number (K)", 
> "Imaginary frequency (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\ 
>  [CapitalOmega]\), \
>   \(i\)]\))"}, RotateLabel -> True, AspectRatio -> 
>   0.5]
> ```